# Ruby, CSV manipulate columns (delete, reorder, rename)

Tags: ruby, csv

Is is possible, in Ruby, to manipulate CSV columns as blocks?

For example I have the bellow CSV:

```
H1,H2,H3
V11,V22,V33
V14,V25,V35
```

I want to:

1. remove the column `H1` and
2. reorder the columns to look like `H3,H2`.
3. rename column `H2` for `HX`

I see examples of manipulating CSVs but they are always *row by row*.

Answer (score 2):

### Delete column

```
csv_table = CSV.read(file_path_in, :headers => true)
csv_table.delete("header_name")
csv_table.to_csv # => The new CSV in string format
```

`CSV::Table` [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Table.html).

### Rename column

** Updated following the @ArupRakshit suggestion:

```
csv_table = CSV.read(file_path_in, :headers => true)
csv_array = csv_table.to_a
csv_array[0][0] = "HEADER_RENAMED" # Renaming the column 1
CSV.generate { |csv_out| csv_array.each { |array| csv_out << array } } # => The new CSV in string format
```

Comment: Use this [`#to_a`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Table.html#method-i-to_a) to convert it to `Array`, and the reorder it and [convert back to `CSV`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#class-CSV-label-Shortcut+Interface) very simple. :)

Comment: I could answer it.. But you half made, so gave you _pointers_ ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this a best way, just quickly tried...

Swapping only headers of the 2nd and 3rd columns.

```
require "csv"

csv_text = File.read("original.csv") 
original = CSV.parse(csv_text)

CSV.open("result.csv", "wb") do |csv|

  trigger = 0 # to check if it's header or not

  original.to_a.each do |row|

    if trigger != 0
      csv << ["#{row[1]}", "#{row[2]}"]
    else
      csv << ["#{row[2]}", "#{row[1]}"]
      trigger = 1
    end

  end

end
```

As **@Arup Rakshit** mentioned, converting to array is helpful.

Comment: This is doing it `row` by `row`.. I'm looking for a solution that treats columns as _entities_.

Comment: It also has a few more problems like that if I want to interchange columns I also want to interchange the headers, I don't know why are you making a difference with the headers.

Comment: In your original post you wanted to swap headers, correct? Or you meant to swap columns as well?

Comment: You are right.. it could be a misunderstanding with my explanation I have updated the question. Still the answers is not what I'm looking because the "element_by_element" think. Thanks any how :)

Answer (score 0):

answer is based on @oscar's code

```
$ cat a.rb
require "csv"

line_num=0

original = CSV.read("original.csv")

original.to_a.each do |row|
  line_num += 1
  if line_num == 1
     puts "H3,HX"
  else
     puts row.values_at(2,1).join(',')
  end
end

$ ruby a.rb
H3,HX
V33,V22
V35,V25
```

Comment: I'm not looking for an _element by element_ solution. I'm looking if there is a way to do these things using _columns_ as elements it self. I'm looking if I'm missing something in the Ruby library that allows these kind of actions.